# How does one find the number of distinct solutions $(x, y)$ of $Y^2=X^3+1$ over a $\mathrm{GF}(p)$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-curves

Given the equation $Y^2=X^3+1$ over the finite field $\mathrm{GF}(p)$, how does one find the number of solution pairs $(x, y)$ that satisfy the equation?

For example, in $\mathrm{GF}(2)$ and $\mathrm{GF}(3)$, there are 2 solutions and 3 solutions respectively: $(0, 1), (1, 0)$ for the former and $(0, -1), (1, 0), (-1, 0)$ for the latter.

In the other primes, those of the form $p \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$, cubing is a multiplicative automorphism and therefore one can easily show that there is exactly $p$ distinct pairs $(x, y)$ with $x, y$ in $\mathrm{GF}(p)$.

What about for other primes? What kind of techniques/methods/theorems can be used to find the number of solutions without brute forcing it for a given $p \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$?

Comment: This type of problem is discussed in great detail in Ireland & Rosen's "A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory," where they use characters of finite fields to count solutions to fairly general diagonal equations over finite fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g$ a generator of $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$. Define the cubic character $\chi_3(g^a) = \zeta_3^a,\chi_3(0)=0$ and the trivial character $\chi_0(x) = 1_{x \in \mathbb{F}_p^\times}$. Then $$\frac{1}{3}(\chi_3(x)+\overline{\chi_3(x)}+\chi_0(x)) = 1_{x \in (\mathbb{F}_p^\times)^3}$$

Define the Jacobi sum
$$J(\chi,\chi) =\sum_{x\in \mathbb{F}_p} \chi(x)\chi(1-x)=\sum_{x\in \mathbb{F}_p} \chi(ax)\chi(1-ax)=\chi(a)^2\sum_{x\in \mathbb{F}_p} \chi(x)\chi(a^{-1}-x), \quad a \in \mathbb{F}_p^\times$$

Thus 
$$\sum_{y \in \mathbb{F}_p} 1_{y^2-1 \in (\mathbb{F}_p^\times)^3} = \frac{1}{3} \sum_{y \in \mathbb{F}_p} (\chi_3(y^2-1)+\overline{\chi_3(y^2-1)}+\chi_0(y^2-1))$$
$$ =\frac{1}{3}( \chi_3(2^{-1})J(\chi_3,\chi_3)+\overline{ \chi_3(2^{-1})J(\chi_3,\chi_3)}+J(\chi_0,\chi_0))$$
If $p \equiv 1 \bmod 3$ then $\mathbb{F}_p$ contains a 3rd root of unity so $x^3 = c$ has $0$ or $3$ solutions.

Therefore, together with $J(\chi_0,\chi_0))=\sum_{y \in \mathbb{F}_p^\times} 1_{1-y \in \mathbb{F}_p^\times} = p-2$,

the point at $\infty$ and the 2 solutions $y^2-1= 0$ we find
$$\# E(\mathbb{F}_p) = 1+2+3 \sum_{y \in \mathbb{F}_p^\times} 1_{y^2-1 \in (\mathbb{F}_p^\times)^3} = p+1+\chi_3(2^{-1})J(\chi_3,\chi_3)+\overline{ \chi_3(2^{-1})J(\chi_3,\chi_3)}$$

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I was thinking of an approach using Gauss sums before hand, but it didn't seem to nice. This approach using jacobi sums is a lot more intuitive!

Comment: @Davehuff If you replace $y^2$ by $z$, you can test with the quadratic character that $z$ is a square, you'll obtain LordShark's formula.

Answer (score 2):

The equation describes the elliptic curve "36a1". The modular form coefficients of it is the OEIS sequence [A000727](http://oeis.org/A000727). The number of solutions is $p-2x$ using the unique solution to $p=x^2+3y^2$ where $x\equiv 1 \pmod {3}$ and $y>0$ if $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ else $p$. More details are in the sequence entry including a reference to Exercise 47.2 in Silverman's *A Friendly Introduction to Number Theory*.

Answer (score 1):

In this case for $p\equiv1\pmod 3$, there is a formula in terms of Jacobi
sums. This can be found in the book of Ireland and Rosen. It is
$$p+J(\rho,\chi)+\overline{J(\rho,\chi)}$$
where $\rho$ and $\chi$ are quadratic and cubic characters of $\Bbb F^\times$. This Jacobi sum can be expressed in terms of the representations
of $p$ in the form $a^2+ab+b^2$.

Comment: so you didn't take in account the point at infinity

Comment: @reuns The OP gives the affine equation....

Comment: Sure. Do you know a short way to put the prime of $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}]$ into play after what I wrote in my answer (or the equivalent with $J(\chi_2,\chi_3)$) ?

Comment: @reuns I would have to sit down with I&R's book, and either find the formula, or work it out for myself. Alas, I don't have the time to do that right now....

Comment: Thank you! I was suspecting there was something that involved $\mathbb{Z}(\zeta_{3})$. I am using this stuff to understand elliptic curves so I